# View query in Excel for exported CRM advanced find

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, export-to-excel

How can I go about viewing/editing the query of an Advanced Find that is exported to Excel? I clicked on Data >> Connections to view the connection properties, but the "Command Text" field is grayed out. We are using a hosted version of MSCRM 2011. I need to be able to change the date range for the exported results based on dates entered by the Excel user. Any suggestions would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just to make sure, did you export the excel as a **dynamic excel**-file? Otherwise it doesn't contain the query.

Comment: Yes, I exported as a "Dynamic Worksheet"